# Joomla is possible get in template the title of page without site name?

Tags: templates, joomla

Need print the title of page without site name, is possible?

I try use it:

`$doc  = JFactory::getDocument(); $doc->getTitle()`

But print with site name...

Answer (score 0):

I used this as a test a few days ago. It worked for me and printed the page name

```
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$mytitle = $doc->getTitle();
echo $mytitle;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just delete site name in your variable? (PHP code based on Lodder one):

```
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$mytitle = str_replace("My Site Name", "", $doc->getTitle());
echo $mytitle;
```